# Card/ Box sizes same for the whole row depending on the largest card

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

How to make the boxes or cards in a 3 column row to get the same height depending on the length of their words inside the card?

I've created a three-column row with three boxes inside of it, which have different amounts of text, so they don't look good when I try to add other boxes below. I tried adding the flex keyword to the CSS but something's not working. I'm not using and don't intend to use bootstrap on this file. 
Hope someone could help me out on this one. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300&display=swap');

        :root {
            --green: #00966B;
            --black: #2c2c54;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            transition: all .2s linear;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        html {
            font-size: 62.5%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            scroll-padding-top: 6.5rem;
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

        .btn {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            background: var(--green);
            color: #fff;
            padding: .8rem 3rem;
            font-size: 1.7rem;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .column33 {
            float: left;
            width: 33.3%;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .product .box-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            gap: 1.5rem;
        }

        .product .box-container .box {
            flex: 1 1 30rem;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 2rem;
            border: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            border-radius: .5rem;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .product .box-container .box h3 {
            color: var(--black);
            font-size: 2.5rem;
        }

        .product .box-container .box .quantity {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            padding-top: 1rem;
            padding-bottom: .5rem;
        }

        .product .box-container .box .quantity span {
            padding: 0 .7rem;
            font-size: 1.7rem;
        }

        .product .box-container .box .btn {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <section class="product" id="product">
        <div class="box-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column33">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Pricing Strategist</h3>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span>Analyzes Data From Multiple Sources, Develop Complex Pricing Models, And Collaborate
                                With Sales And Marketing Teams To Develop Sales Strategies.</span>
                        </div>
                        <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="column33">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Vice Manager</h3>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span>Manages The Supermarket In Absence Of The Manager</span>
                        </div>
                        <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="column33">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Web Analyst</h3>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span>Responsible For Developing, Modifying And Maintaining Broad/Complex Computer
                                Systems.</span>
                        </div>
                        <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I helped you, at least give me an up-vote please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tweeked your code to make them all the same height and align all the text with each other.

What you needed is to have the inner containers to have 100% in height in order for the content to fill upp the white spaces from top to bottom. You also needed to use flex on the inner containers to place the inner content evenely. I've added comments on each css-code to explain each thing I've added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300&display=swap');

    :root {
      --green: #00966B;
      --black: #2c2c54;
    }

    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      transition: all .2s linear;
      font-size: 100%;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }

    html {
      font-size: 62.5%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      scroll-padding-top: 6.5rem;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      background: var(--green);
      color: #fff;
      padding: .8rem 3rem;
      font-size: 1.7rem;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .column33 {
      height: 100%;
      /* height 100% to make it go all the way from top to bottom */
      width: 33.3%;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    .row {
      content: "";
      display: flex;
      /* use flex instead of table */
      clear: both;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }

    .product .box-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 1.5rem;
    }

    .product .box-container .box {
      flex: 1 1 30rem;
      display: flex;
      /* make it a flex container to place things evenely inside with "justify-content" */
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      /* add this to put space between the inner elements */
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2rem;
      border: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
      border-radius: .5rem;
      /* overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;  I would remove this because they are not needed  (overflow and position) */
      height: 100%;
      /* also 100% height here to make inner container go all the way from top to bottom */
    }

    .product .box-container .box h3 {
      color: var(--black);
      font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    .product .box-container .box .quantity {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: start; /* to place all text at the beginning of the inner container */ 
      height: 100%; /* make it take up all the space inside the inner container */
      padding-top: 1rem;
      padding-bottom: .5rem;

    }

    .product .box-container .box .quantity span {
      padding: 0 .7rem;
      font-size: 1.7rem;
    }

    .product .box-container .box .btn {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="product" id="product">
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column33">
          <div class="box">
            <h3>Pricing Strategist</h3>
            <div class="quantity">
              <span>Analyzes Data From Multiple Sources, Develop Complex Pricing Models, And Collaborate
                With Sales And Marketing Teams To Develop Sales Strategies.</span>
            </div>
            <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column33">
          <div class="box">
            <h3>Vice Manager</h3>
            <div class="quantity">
              <span>Manages The Supermarket In Absence Of The Manager</span>
            </div>
            <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column33">
          <div class="box">
            <h3>Web Analyst</h3>
            <div class="quantity">
              <span>Responsible For Developing, Modifying And Maintaining Broad/Complex Computer
                Systems.</span>
            </div>
            <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with grid:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300&display=swap');

        :root {
            --green: #00966B;
            --black: #2c2c54;
        }

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            transition: all .2s linear;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        html {
            font-size: 62.5%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            scroll-padding-top: 6.5rem;
            scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }

        .btn {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            background: var(--green);
            color: #fff;
            padding: .8rem 3rem;
            font-size: 1.7rem;
            text-align: center;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .column33 {
           /* float: left;
            width: 33.3%;*/
            padding: 10px;
        }

        /* Clear floats after the columns */
        .row {
 
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            
            justify-items: center;
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        .product .box-container {
            /*display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            gap: 1.5rem;*/
        }

        .product .box-container .box {
            /*flex: 1 1 30rem;*/
            text-align: center;
            padding: 2rem;
            border: .1rem solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
            border-radius: .5rem;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: minmax(min-content, 1fr) 3fr auto;
        }

        .product .box-container .box h3 {
            color: var(--black);
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            
        }

        .product .box-container .box .quantity {
            /*display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;*/
            padding-top: 1rem;
            padding-bottom: .5rem;
            align-self: start;
        }

        .product .box-container .box .quantity span {
            padding: 0 .7rem;
            font-size: 1.7rem;
        }

        .product .box-container .box .btn {
            display: block;
            align-self: end;
        }
```

```html
<body>

    <section class="product" id="product">
        <div class="box-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column33">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Pricing Strategist</h3>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span>Analyzes Data From Multiple Sources, Develop Complex Pricing Models, And Collaborate
                                With Sales And Marketing Teams To Develop Sales Strategies.</span>
                        </div>
                        <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="column33">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Vice Manager</h3>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span>Manages The Supermarket In Absence Of The Manager</span>
                        </div>
                        <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="column33">
                    <div class="box">
                        <h3>Web Analyst</h3>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span>Responsible For Developing, Modifying And Maintaining Broad/Complex Computer
                                Systems.</span>
                        </div>
                        <a onclick="Apply('${positions[i].Title}')" href="#" class="btn">Apply</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```